# how to run python as backend in live with flutter

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, dart

I need to run in flutter an algorithm that I have done in python about facial recognition. the problem is that it draws the points in the camera (in live). An API that makes a request does not work for me since it has to be constantly passing data to the backend (python) as input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use WebSocket, maybe this packet can help you [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel)